# Modify the store example to protect state

Tags: vue.js

Vue [gives this example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) of a simple store, where state is modified by calling an action on the store...

```
var store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    message: 'Hello!'
  },
  setMessageAction (newValue) {
    if (this.debug) console.log('setMessageAction triggered with', newValue)
    this.state.message = newValue
  },
  clearMessageAction () {
    if (this.debug) console.log('clearMessageAction triggered')
    this.state.message = ''
  }
}
```

But state is a public property of store, and no-one is obliged to pass by `setMessageAction()` to modify it. Is there a simple trick to protect state, but still have it observed by vue? I can't think of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not support [access modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers); everything is public.

There are various ways of encapsulating private implementation details in JavaScript, but in your example the store's state needs to be public so that it can be assigned to the component's data.

Vuex has a [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/strict.html) which, if enabled, will throw an error if the state is modified outside of mutation handlers.